# in which file would I find the definition of (->)

Tags: haskell

in which file would I find the definition of (->)

My assumption is that this is defined somewhere in GHC.something, but it is tricky to search for.

Answer (score 6):

`->` is a keyword, not an infix-style function. It is not defined in the Haskell base libraries, and could not be.

(EDIT: But as frasertweedale and Rein Henrichs noted, it's given special treatment by the compiler so that `(->)` can be treated as a regular type constructor.)

Answer (score 4):

`(->)`, within the Haskell language itself, is **not a keyword** but
a *type constructor*.  To wit:

```
λ> :i (->)
data (->) t1 t2     -- Defined in ‘GHC.Prim’
infixr 0 `(->)`
instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Functor ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Applicative ((->) a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

It is just an infix type constructor, and you can use it just
like any other type constructor.

The question of where it is defined is a bit trickier.
In the source code for `GHC.Base` you will find the following
comment:

> ```
> GHC.Prim    Has no implementation.  It defines built-in things, and
>             by importing it you bring them into scope.
>             The source file is GHC.Prim.hi-boot, which is just
>             copied to make GHC.Prim.hi
> ```

GHC's build process directly produces an interface file exposing the behaviour associated with `(->)`.

Comment: `->` is still pretty deeply special magic. If you ask GHCi `:i (->)`, it reports "Defined in `GHC.Prim`", but if you ask `:i (GHC.Prim.->)`, it says "Not in scope: `GHC.Prim.->`". Yes, it's a type constructor, but it's not *just* a type constructor. Two major aspects of its weirdness: 1. With `RankNTypes`, it can be applied to a quantified type. 2. With `GADTs` or `GADTSyntax`, the type being defined must appear at the end of the last arrow in the type of each constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`(->)` is not a keyword but an infix-style function (as you can pass it as a parameter and can be partially applied), but because of its importance, it is treated by the compiler specially: https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/75bf11c037d9e82f95ac9779bfd2b1432835bd76/compiler/types/TyCoRep.hs#L287

Comment: That's the compiler source, not the runtime. -> is most certainly a keyword; see https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#-.3E

Comment: `->` is a keyword with special handling in type declarations to make it usable as if it were an infix type constructor. You are both right. Or both wrong. Depending on how you want to look at it.